# Is there a way of pasting code snippets/blocks in gmail/wave/gdocs?

Tags: php, javascript, html, gmail

Often, I want to email some code without attaching a file. Are there any gmail/google wave/gdocs plugins for code sharing?

Gmail would obviously be the most useful.

Comment: [markdown-here](http://markdown-here.com/) is a chrome plugin that allows you to use markdown in emails. It has code sections with syntax highlighting. For example \`\`\`js `NEWLINE` `code` `NEWLINE` \`\`\` would highlight javascript code on a nice grey background when markdown is toggled on.

Answer (score 8):

You could use service like [pastie](http://pastie.org) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.org) and then link it in your mail.

Alternatively you can also use [ToHTML](http://tohtml.com/) to generate HTML and then copy/paste it in your mail.

Comment: ToHTML service looks like the perfect solution - contains auto-syntax highlighting for a huge number of languages (including markup, DB and rare ones) and generated HTML is feasible for Gmail/Google group/GDocs messages (they display it as formatted highlighted code). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I usually just set the font to something monospaced and hit paste....

There is a [Code prettifier](http://code.google.com/p/wave-code-prettifier/) gadget for wave that might help.

Comment: Courier New is a monospaced font that appears in Gmail's font dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [code.google.com](http://code.google.com). That might be a good solution for you. Also, Google recently bought EtherPad, so there might hopefully be a good solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is this.  https://wave.google.com/wave/#restored:wave:googlewave.com!w%252By2RZbMagM

This might be the same one gnarf posted.

Comment: Not the same one, but this one looks pretty good too..

Answer (score -1):

You can attach a link and use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)