# How to mail a JS code to Gmail, not to execute, but just to display

Tags: codeigniter, security, xss

I need to send some `js` code to my users' email id(can be any many client) so that the users can just copy and use the code in their websites. The code involves `<script></script>`.But when I tried this with `GMail`, it seems to be replacing the tags with `[removed]`, and making my code not useful. **I read it is not possible to send executable code snippets to mail clients like Gmail**,but still I find some apps doing this.But I am not trying to execute my code in the mailbox, instead I just want to display.Is there any workaround for this?

**edit**
It seems my framework, `codeIgniter` is actually doing this. This is what I tried

```
$mail_subject = $this->input->post('message', false);
```

and

```
$mail_subject = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('message'), false);
```

In the `Security` core class, I find `javascript` tags under `$_never_allowed_regex`.But how to allow them?

**Solved** by using a `htmlspecialchars()` function

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684200/is-there-a-way-of-pasting-code-snippets-blocks-in-gmail-wave-gdocs

Comment: Add it in a text file as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `htmlentities()` to convert into html special characters

Comment: Is this your expected solution or ?